# Highcharts navigation button and fullscreen button in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, fullscreen

The functionality (print, export to Excel etc) of the navigation button of highcharts is linked to a bootstrap dropdown menu in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/0yy5qfc7/9/) example.

In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/o3zbk87w/) example, a fullscreen button with the redraw function of highcharts is linked so that the graph maintains the correct ratio.

Unfortunately, I can not combine both in a graph. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/0yy5qfc7/12/) example

HTML

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3>Panel title
            <ul class="list-inline panel-actions">
              <li><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen" class='fullscreen-btn' role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="print">Print</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="png">Download PNG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="jpeg">Download JPEG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="pdf">Download PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="svg">Download SVG</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="csv">Download CSV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="xls">Download XLS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3>Panel title
            <ul class="list-inline panel-actions">
              <li><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen2" class='fullscreen-btn' role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="print2">Print</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="png2">Download PNG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="jpeg2">Download JPEG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="pdf2">Download PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="svg2">Download SVG</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="csv2">Download CSV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="xls2">Download XLS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="container2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chart1Info = {
    containerId: 'container',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };
  var chart2Info = {
    containerId: 'container2',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Chart2 Title'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };

  function drawChart(chartInfo) {
    // Properties that vary by chart should be defined in chartInfo
    // Any properties that are the same for all charts are added here 
    chartInfo.responsive = {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };
    Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
  }
  //Toggle fullscreen
  $(".fullscreen-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('i')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-resize-full')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-resize-small');
    $(this).closest('.panel').toggleClass('panel-fullscreen');
    var chartInfo = $this.attr("id") === 'panel-fullscreen' ? chart1Info : chart2Info;
    console.log($this.id, chartInfo);
    drawChart(chartInfo);
  });
  drawChart(chart1Info);
  drawChart(chart2Info);
});





// Export buttons
$('#png').click(function() {
  chart1Info.exportChart();
});

$('#jpeg').click(function() {
  chart1Info.exportChart({
    type: 'jpeg',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
});

$('#pdf').click(function() {
  chart.exportChart({
    type: 'pdf',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
});

$('#svg').click(function() {
  chart1Info.exportChart({
    type: 'SVG',
    filename: 'my-svg'
  });
});

document.getElementById('csv').onclick = () => {
  chart1Info.downloadCSV()
};

document.getElementById('xls').onclick = () => {
  chart1Info.downloadXLS()
}

$('#print').click(function() {
  chart1Info.print();
});


$('#png2').click(function() {
  chart2Info.exportChart();
});

$('#jpeg2').click(function() {
  chart2Info.exportChart({
    type: 'jpeg',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
});

$('#pdf2').click(function() {
  chart2Info.exportChart({
    type: 'pdf',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
});

$('#svg2').click(function() {
  chart2Info.exportChart({
    type: 'SVG',
    filename: 'my-svg'
  });
});

document.getElementById('csv2').onclick = () => {
  chart2.downloadCSV()
};

document.getElementById('xls2').onclick = () => {
  chart2Info.downloadXLS()
}

$('#print2').click(function() {
  chart2Info.print();
});
```

CSS

```
.panel-actions {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.panel-actions a {
  color: #333;
}

.panel-fullscreen {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Hi Kees de Jager, please specify in more detail what are your requirements. Do you want to have both buttons next to each other?

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, both buttons at the top of the panel must be visible. This also applies in the case of fullscreen mode. Which is now the case in the third example. In the first example you can see that functionality (print, export to excel etc) of the navigation button of highcharts works in bootstrap. In the second example you see the working fullscreen button. In the third example I added a button for both fullscreen and the navigation button. Unfortunately now only the fullscreen button works but not the navigation button. I would like to know how I can get the navigation button working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code. First of them is scope of variables - part of them are outside of main function. The second is that when you call for example downloadCSV(), you have to refer to created chart not to the chart options.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var charts = [];
  var chart1Info = {
    containerId: 'container',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };
  var chart2Info = {
    containerId: 'container2',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Chart2 Title'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };

  function drawChart(chartInfo) {
    // Properties that vary by chart should be defined in chartInfo
    // Any properties that are the same for all charts are added here 
    chartInfo.responsive = {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };

    if (chartInfo == chart1Info) {
      charts[0] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    } else {
      charts[1] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    }

  }
  //Toggle fullscreen
  $(".fullscreen-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('i')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-resize-full')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-resize-small');
    $(this).closest('.panel').toggleClass('panel-fullscreen');
    var chartInfo = $this.attr("id") === 'panel-fullscreen' ? chart1Info : chart2Info;
    console.log($this.id, chartInfo);
    drawChart(chartInfo);
  });

  drawChart(chart1Info);
  drawChart(chart2Info);



  // Export buttons
  $('#png').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart();
  });

  $('#jpeg').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'jpeg',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#pdf').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'pdf',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#svg').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'SVG',
      filename: 'my-svg'
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('csv').onclick = () => {
    charts[0].downloadCSV()
  };

  document.getElementById('xls').onclick = () => {
    charts[0].downloadXLS()
  }

  $('#print').click(function() {
    charts[0].print();
  });


  $('#png2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart();
  });

  $('#jpeg2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'jpeg',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#pdf2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'pdf',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#svg2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'SVG',
      filename: 'my-svg'
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('csv2').onclick = () => {
    charts[1].downloadCSV()
  };

  document.getElementById('xls2').onclick = () => {
    charts[1].downloadXLS()
  }

  $('#print2').click(function() {
    charts[1].print();
  });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ug1z8j6r/

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek this is exactly what i was looking for!!! Sometimes the answer is so simple. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm trying to convert your example with panels to bootstrap 4 with cards. But unfortunately the fullscreen does not work. I adjusted the glyphicon for fontawesome.  I also changed the javascript part. Do you have any idea what the problem is? Thanks again for your time. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/g7bjhw2u/

Comment: Hi Kees de Jager, fixed position from panel-fullscreen class is overridden by relative position from card class: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2uoqkra8/

Comment: Thanks again!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I am again having a problem that I do not know how to use the fullscreen redraw on more than two cards. I do not know how to add a third variable to this piece: "var chartInfo = $ this.attr (" id ") === 'panel-fullscreen'? Chart1Info: chart2Info;". I have made an example where this part is not complete yet. Hopefully you can help me again! http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/71hxmkd8/

Comment: Hi Kees de Jager, you have to assign correct chart options to 'chartInfo' variable. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/khz459yp/

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, thanks again mate! I spent half a day on this problem without any solution. So thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: Thanks it's very useful